# JS Report - Using $localizedResource inside JS function

Tags: javascript, html, localization, jsreport

I have a part of table like below.

```
<tr>
<td class='col-narrow'>{{$localizedResource.DATE}}</td>
<td class='col-narrow'>{{$localizedResource.TIME}}</td>
<td class='col-narrow'>{{$localizedResource.DAY}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='col-narrow'>{{date}}</td>
<td class='col-narrow'>{{time}}</td>
<td class='col-narrow'>{{day}}</td> // need to translate this
</tr>
```

I need to translate the {{Day}} in different languages which i receive from api response. I have added the keys in the locales files for all the days and tried doing the below which unfortunately did not work

```
function translateKey(key){
    if(key){
    const message = key.toUpperCase();
    const newKey = this.$localizedresource.message;
    return newKey;
    }
}
```

and in the template i tried the following

```
 <td class='col-narrow'>{{ translateKey day}}</td>
```

Can anyone help me figure out the issue here

Answer (score 0):

jsreport already has a function for that, try `{{localize day "localization"}}`,
"localization" is the folder name of locale files

https://jsreport.net/learn/localization#documentation